# back-end for virtual filesystem as seen by Windows Explorer?

Tags: filesystems

I'd like to write a fairly simple server-side virtual filesystem in either Python (preferably) or Java (less preferably), and I'm wondering if there's any well-known framework that will allow me to do so with an off-the shelf client.

e.g.:

- users install some kind of client (like dropbox or wuala) that presents a Windows Explorer view of the filesystem, and turns it into appropriate requests to the server (WebDAV?)
- I setup/configure some software on my server that receives the WebDAV operations, and delegates them to my software
- I write my software to implement various hooks (read/write/list files)

Comment: You can create an SFTP server or WebDAV server and have more or less common clients such as ExpanDrive or our SFTP Net Drive connect to such server. With this approach you have full control over requests coming from the client. Unfortunately I don't know ready to use Python or Java libraries for creating SFTP or WebDAV servers. Our SecureBlackbox product offers such components for .NET and VCL, and we plan to release Java edition of SecureBlackbox in 3-4 months (probably python bindings to .so module will also be offered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the builtin Tomcat class [org.apache.catalina.servlets.WebdavServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/WebdavServlet.html) is what I want, I just need to subclass the individual doXXXX methods.